# How to prefix money in the status bar of the R shiny widget package?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I tried to run some code, but they all convert numbers to strings, so shiny can't calculate it.
Is there a way to show the numbers in the progress bar in the shinyWidgets package as money?

Eg .: R$1.000.000,70/R$5.000.000,29

(In Brazil, where I speak from, we use a dot as a thousand separator and a comma as a decimal separator)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
        progressBar(id = "pb1", value = 1000000.70, 
                    total = 5000000.29, status = "info", display_pct = TRUE, striped = TRUE, 
                    title = "DONATION"),

        progressBar(id = "pb2", value = as.numeric(1000000.70, options(scipen=999)), 
                    total = as.numeric(5000000.29, options(scipen=999), status = "info", display_pct = TRUE, striped = TRUE, 
                    title = "DONATION")
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```